# What is the meaning of External Dependencies folder in VS Resolution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio

VS automatically generated it, and I didn't find introduction of this folder in official document.

Can anyone explain the meaning of this folder, and Why VS Choose to create it?

Answer (score 0):

The External Dependencies folder is populated by IntelliSense: the contents of the folder do not affect the build at all (you can in fact disable the folder in the UI). You need to actually include the header (using a #include directive) to use it.

Comment: I saw this answer in other question, but what I want to know is the use of External Dependencies folder.